# Any idea to start drawing this dynamic figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks-add

[image: armatures]

I have not put the MWE because I don't know where to start and check for packages to do the job.

Comment: Maybe helpful links: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61316/124842, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/356562/124842, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/104062/124842,https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/204897/124842

Comment: I already check in the forum, it is not a duplicate I want to get help how to begin drawing this image, please get help?

Comment: The linked question addresses exactly your question: where to begin and which package to use, where to look for information. Answers provide a full range of options and examples. There really isn't much point in duplicating that information here. Your question is the same general one about the options you have for drawing an image. (You've also asked similar questions before, so it seems odd that you don't know even which packages you might use. But whatever the reason, the answers to the linked question set out your options.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use TikZ, here is a start for you:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,10) -- (5,10); % line between 2 points, coordinates of points in ()
\draw (0,9) -- node[above]{$A$} (5,9); % and with some text above it
\draw (0,8) -- node[below]{$B_1$} (5,8); % or below
\draw (0,7) -- node[below]{$B_1$} node[above]{$A$} (5,7); % or both
\draw[<-] (0,6) -- (5,6); % arrow at the start
\draw[->] (0,5) -- (5,5); % or at the end
\draw[<->] (0,4) -- (5,4); % or at both ends
\draw[very thick] (0,3) -- (5,3); % thick line
\draw[line width=5pt] (0,2) -- (5,2); % arbitarry line width
\draw[dashed] (0,1) -- (5,1); % dashed line
\draw[red] (0,0) -- (5,0); % colored line
\draw (6,0) rectangle (7,10); % a rectangle
\draw (8,0) -- node[left] {$C_n$} (8,10); % some text left from line
\draw (9,0) -- node[right] {$D$} (9,10); % or right of it
\draw[->] (10,0) -- (10,9) node[anchor=south west] {$X$}; % some text at the end of the line
\draw[<-,very thick] (11,1) node[anchor=north east] {$Y$} -- (11,10); % or at the start
\fill (11,5.5) circle (0.1); % a circle at a given coordinate
\node[anchor=north west] at (6,10) {$P$}; % some text near a point
\draw[densely dashed] (12,0) -- (12,3); % different styles for dashed lines
\draw[dashed] (12,3.5) -- (12,6.5);
\draw[loosely dashed] (12,7) -- (12,10);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Ti*k*Z sampler]

By combining these examples and selecting proper coordinates you can draw your picture.

TikZ uses 1cm as its unit length. You can also use lengths for the coordinates (e.g. `(1mm,10pt)`). For nicer arrows see chapter 16 of the [pgf manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf). A lot more can be done with TikZ. Just search for the commands and options in the maual.

Comment: Ok, thanks for giving me the opportunity to try it to myself. I am going to work on it and post my result.